# Detecting logout or timeout in InAppBrowse

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have built a Cordova app which is a hybrid to load a betting website.  The native screens allow for an Api login which requires a user to enter a username and password afterwhich they are prompted to enter a Pin.

The WebApi will register the device and receive a random token back which is a temp key. I use this key to invoke the Cordova InAppBrowser http://mybettingsite.com/Account/Login?token=12123nm1231n23kj12n3j1k2n3k1j

This will automate the login as a new session in the inAppBrowser.

My issue is now backward detection.  If the user hits the logout button or get's timed out within the InAppBrowser I want to be able to detect these actions within the native app and therefore reload the login and/or pin screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might consider changing the title to "Detecting logout or timeout in InAppBrowser" or something like that...Right now the title is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, changed this now